# Printing vertices from a graph in order of the number of shared adjacent they have with a given vertex

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am a bit stuck with this problem at the moment and I wouldn't mind a hint.What we have  is a graph ,a  given starting vertex and a number 'n' of vertex to be displayed,what I need to accomplish is print out n number of vertices so that the first couple of vertices are adjacent for the adjacent of the starting vertex,the next couple are adjacent to the previous once and so on.The order of the vertexes from each level though must be in a descending order depending on the number of duplicating adjacent they have with the starting vertex.

I know that it would be good to use BFS but I am having a problem in ordering the  vertexes so that they go from the ones with the biggest duplicating adjacent to the ones with the fewest.

[image]

For example if the starting vertex is '0' and we need 9 vertices the output should be:(lvl 1)5 4 3 6 (lvl2)8 7 9 10 11

Comment: Start by building an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Then, get a list of all the children of the starting node. The first level of your output will be children of those nodes. Once you have the first level, find the children of *those* nodes, etc. It's very helpful to work that problem by hand on paper with a small graph before trying to write code for it.

Comment: Yeah that actually really similar to what I did,I already manage  to solve it,thanks for the hand thought :).